# Frame page modules created using Tkinter (supposed to load on button clicks) loads inappropriately at the start of the application

Tags: python, tkinter

I have coded a GUI with TKinter. The application consists of many pages. These pages are loaded on click of respective buttons. The only page that is supposed to load on the start is the start page. However, the SearchAndModifySubsPage, EmployeeManagementPage, SearchAndModifyEmpPage flashes briefly before the start page loads. But these pages (SearchAndModifySubsPage, EmployeeManagementPage, SearchAndModifyEmpPage) are only supposed to load when the button is clicked.

Note that each of these pages are individual classes with their own functionality and they have more than 1000 lines of code.

Below is the code for a class that organizes the other pages and loads the start page.

```
class KFMS(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        Tk.wm_title(self, 'KGMS')
        Tk.iconbitmap(self, default=Parameters.Path.EICO)

        self.container = Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.configure(background=Parameters.Constants.BACKGROUND)

        self.frames = {}

        # Menubar
        menubar = Menu(self.container)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        # submenu
        submenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=submenu)
        submenu.add_command(label='Home', command=lambda: self.show_frame(StartPage))
        submenu.add_command(label='KK', command=lambda: self.show_frame(KKPage))
        submenu.add_separator()
        submenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.destroy)

        submenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=submenu)
        submenu.add_command(label='User guide')
        submenu.add_command(label='Support')

        # Tag
        tagFrame = Frame(self)
        tagFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        tagFrame.config(bg="blue")
        # tagFrame.configure(background=Parameters.Constants.BACKGROUND)
        ds = PhotoImage(file=Parameters.Path.DSG)
        dsl = Label(image=ds)
        dsl.image = ds
        dsLabel = Label(tagFrame, text='dear Sky', image=ds, compound="right", font=("Purisa", 20, "italic"),
                        background=Parameters.Constants.BACKGROUND, fg="#888B89")  # A5A9A7
        dsLabel.pack(side="right", fill=X)

    def framePages(self):
        for F in (StartPage, AdminPage, KFPage, KKPage,
                  SubsPage, AddSubsPage, SearchAndModifySubsPage, SubscriberInformationPage, SubscriberHistoryPage,
                  EmployeeManagementPage, AddNewEmpPage, SearchAndModifyEmpPage, EmployeeInformationPage,
                  EmployeeLogPage):
            frame = F(self.container, self)
            frame.configure(background=Parameters.Constants.BACKGROUND)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)



    def show_frame(self, controller):
        try:
            frame = self.frames[controller]
            frame.tkraise()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    kfms = KFMS()
    kfms.geometry("1280x720")
    kfms.wm_state('zoomed')
    # kfms.resizable(0, 0)
    kfms.framePages()
    # t = Thread()
    # t.daemon = True
    # t.start()
    kfms.mainloop()
```

On the Button click I use the following command to redirect to the required pages.

```
searchModifyButton = Button(gridFrame, text="Search & Modify Employee", image=photo, compound=TOP,
                                    font=(Parameters.Constants.FONT, Parameters.Constants.FONT_SIZE),
                                    fg=Parameters.Constants.FG, cursor="hand2",
                                    background=Parameters.Constants.BACKGROUND,
                                    borderwidth=0, command=lambda :self.controller.show_frame(SearchAndModifyEmpPage))
        # self.after_idle(self.searchRedirect) this doesn't help resolve the issue

        searchModifyButton.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=PADY)
```

I have tried threading the GUI and used after_idle method. But nothing seemed to work.
I apologize since won't be able to provide more code than this to reproduce the problem.
Please help me resolve this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is clearly creating every page at startup. If you don't want them created on startup, you need to change the way you are managing the windows. The fact that they are briefly appearing says to me that you're calling `update` inside one or more of the `__init__` methods of one or more of those classes.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for your reply. You are right. All the 1000 lines of code in each and every class was in the `__init__` method. So I put only the calling of `__init__` of the super class in the `__init__` of the current classes, and rest of the code under a different method. This resolved my issue. If you could post your comment as an answer, that would be great.Thank you so much.